# Recursive Macros

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'm trying to create a macro that can operate recursively. It needs to create a link between two node in one (`->`) or two (`<->`) directions. I believe it's an issue with the `...` and can't seem to get it to work.

**Created Structure**

```
(define-struct node (name edges) #:transparent)
```

**Desired Example Input and Output**

```
> (edges node1 <-> node2 -> node3)
> node1
> (node 'node1 '(node2))
> node2
> (node 'node2 '(node1 node3))
> node3
> (node 'node3 '())
```

**Current Input and Output**

```
> (edges node1 -> node2 node3)
> node1
> (node 'node1 '(node2 node3))
```

**Code**

```
(define-syntax edge
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(edge node-name1 node-name2)
     (begin (set! node-name1 (make-node (quote node-name1) (add-unique (node-name node-name2) (node-edges node-name1)))))]))

(define-syntax edges
  (syntax-rules (-> <->)
    [(edges node-name1 -> node-name2 ...) 
     (begin (edge node-name1 node-name2 ...))]
    [(edges node-name1 <-> node-name2 ...)
     (begin (edge node-name1 node-name2) ...
            (edge node-name2 node-name1)
            ...)]))
```

The nodes are previously defined.

Comment: i feel like `edge` shouldn't be a macro, in this case; but that's mostly just my spidey sense talking

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
(define-syntax edges
  (syntax-rules (-> <->)
    [(edges _)
     (begin)]
    [(edges node-name1 -> node-name2 ...) 
     (begin (edge node-name1 (edges node-name2 ...)))]
    [(edges node-name1 <-> node-name2 ...)
     (begin (edge node-name1 node-name2) ...
            (edge node-name2 node-name1)
            ...)]))
```